How to get the value of an input variable from a function using OneOf C#
I want to get the input value from a function.
I call the function:
Name=GetName(Paul)

Where Paul is a member of ClassA, ClassB or Class C. I want to use the following function to call other functions with Paul as an input depending on the class Paul is really in.
public static string GetName(OneOf<ClassA,ClassB,ClassC> input)
{
    var Variable = input.Match(
    ClassA => doSomethingWithA(input),
    ClassB => doSomethingWithB(input),
    ClassC => doSomethingWithC(input),
    );
}

When I try to input.Value or something like that, I just get the name of the class, but not Paul, which is unfortunate, because then I don't have the input I need for my functions doSomethingWith.
Has someone an idea how to solve this? It doesn't have to use the OneOf-Package.

Sounds like those three classes should all just implement and interface, and you should be coding to that, rather than trying to special case all three of these classes like this all through your business logic.

is Paul a member of or an instance of?

@IvanPetrov What's the difference?

@Martin it sounds that you want to check if Paul is of type ClassA or ClassB or ClassC, not that whether Paul is a member (field,property, method) of ClassA, ClassB or ClassC.

@IvanPetrov Yes, that is the case. So Paul is an instance?

You can use a lambda function based on the type of input and get the appropriate name accordingly.
Refer the code below:
using System;
using OneOf;

public class ClassA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ClassA(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ClassB(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ClassC(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A = new ClassA("Paul");
        var B = new ClassB("John");
        var C = new ClassC("Sam");

        OneOf<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC> inputA = A;
        OneOf<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC> inputB = B;
        OneOf<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC> inputC = C;

        Console.WriteLine("Class A Name : "+GetName(inputA)); // Class A Name : Paul
        Console.WriteLine("Class B Name : "+GetName(inputB)); // Class B Name : John
        Console.WriteLine("Class C Name : "+GetName(inputC)); // Class C Name : Sam
    }


    /*
    * Method get Name given a OneOf from Class A , B , C
    */

    public static string GetName(OneOf<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC> input)
    {
        var variable = input.Match(
            classA => classA.Name,
            classB => classB.Name,
            classC => classC.Name
        );

        return variable;
    }
}


Refer to the working .netfiddle here


Worked like a charme. Thanks to you!

@Martin appreciate it if you could mark it as the correct answer and give it an upvote.. Thanks in advance.


It doesn't have to use the OneOf-Package

If it doesn't have to use your package, you can use standard C# and switch expressions with pattern matching to achieve the same (and probably more efficiently as well):
object? input = ...; // or common interface or class
var name = input switch
{
    ClassA { } classA => classA.Name,
    ClassB { } classB => classB.Name,
    ClassC { } classC => classC.Name,
};

Alternatively, you can also use dynamic code for duck typing:
dynamic input = ...;
var name = input.Name;

